# sending tcp package by pressing samsung bixby button

Tags: android, android-studio, xamarin, bixby, bixbystudio

I have an app on my phone which has one button: Toggle Light. This app tells my raspberry to toggle the light in my room. This part works. (btw. the app is written in xamarin)

Until yet I always just used the bixby button to open my app and then I have to press the button in the app. But I want to have the bixby button to just send the tcp package.

- Could it be possible to have an "invisible" app which launches but doesnt have an gui?
- I saw that there is a bixby studio in which you can code your own bixby commands but what I saw this also opens an gui.

So how can I have my bixby button to just not show an gui?

Comment: I don't think that is possible. There needs to be some feedback (audio or visual) to indicate acknowledgement. You can shorten the need to look by linking the launch intent to sending the tcp package, but to me that seems error-prone rather than associating voice to "toggle light" with existing SmartThings: https://smartthings.developer.samsung.com/docs/devices/working-with-bixby.html

Answer (score 2):

I think this is possible. Bixby Studio is the IDE for writing Bixby apps or "capsules". You will be using it to write a very simple natural language application that is composed of several data models plus a javascript action file. The javascript is the portion that would send off the tcp request.  You can define the capsule so that as soon as the capsule is invoked by a natural language request like "In Toggle Light, turn on light" it will run the Javascript and send the tcp request, then present you with an acknowledgment. "I turned on the light."